# Why doesn't work my code, even though it is true?

Tags: c

this code firstly takes two words for user. Then, it check those length with a function. Then the code send the words and their length to another function for it to find commen letters in these words. The same function also print that how many commen letters they have.(The user enter just lower letter or just capital letters)

for example:

input1: emirhan

input2: celek

output: The words that you entered have 2 common letters

output shouldn't be 3 because input2 (celek) has 2 'e' and the code count just one of them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 40

int length(char word[30]) {

    int uzun;
    uzun = strlen(word) - 1;
    return uzun;

}

int equation(char x[MAX], char y[MAX], int length1, int length2) {

    int i, j, k, l;
    int sayac = 0; // sayac  means counter

    if (length1 >= length2) {
        for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < length2; i++) {
                if (x[i] == y[j]) { // if the code find a common letter,it will enter if
                    sayac++;
                    for (k = i + 1; k < length1; k++) { //This 'for' check that does first word same letter or not?
                        if (x[k] == x[i]) {
                            sayac--;
                        }
                    }
                    for (l = j + 1; l < length2; l++) { //This 'for' check that does second word same letter or not?
                        if (y[l] == y[j]) {
                            sayac--;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if (length1 < length2) {
        for (i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < length1; i++) {
                if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                    sayac++;
                    for (k = i + 1; k < length2; k++) {
                        if (x[k] == x[i]) {
                            sayac--;
                        }
                    }
                    for (l = j + 1; l < length1; l++) {
                        if (y[l] == y[j]) {
                            sayac--;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    printf("The words that you entered have %d common letters", sayac);
}

int main() {
    char x[MAX]; //input1
    char y[MAX]; //input2

    int length1; // length of first word
    int length2; // length of second word

    printf("PLS, enter the first word:");
    fgets(x, sizeof(x), stdin);
    printf("PLS, enter the second word:");
    fgets(y, sizeof(y), stdin);

    length1 = length(x);
    length2 = length(y);

    equation(x, y, length1, length2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should never ever use `gets`. It is considered dangeruous and was removed from C standard decades ago. Use `fgets` instead. (And be aware that it stores trailing `\n` in the buffer)

Comment: What is purpose of your `length` function? If you have a homework task to write your own `strlen` then you should not use `strlen`. If you don't have such a task, why not use `strlen` directly? And please note that `strlen` does not return an `int` but a `size_t`.

Comment: 2 looks like a right answer. Whats should be answer if both inputs gonna be `celek`? 7 or 5?

Comment: In the alternative code block in function `equation` you are looping to the wrong limits, so you will index string `x` beyond its input length, and string `y` will have part ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the my code again and I solved the problem. I had a mistake in loops. I coded loops again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> 

#define MAX 40

int length(char word[30]) {

    int uzun;
    uzun = strlen(word) - 1;
    return uzun;
    
}

void equation(char x[MAX], char y[MAX], int length1, int length2) {

    int i, j, k, l;
    int sayac = 0; // sayac  means counter

        for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
                if (x[i] == y[j]) { // if the code find a common letter,it will enter if
                    sayac++;
                    for (k = i + 1; k < length1; k++) { //This 'for' check that does first word same letter or not?
                        if (x[k] == x[i]) { 
                            sayac--;
                        }
                    }
                    for (l = j + 1; l < length2; l++) { //This 'for' check that does second word same letter or not?
                        if (y[l] == y[j]) {
                            sayac--;
                        }
                    } 
                }

            }
        }
    

    
    printf("The words that you entered have %d common letters", sayac);
} 

int main() {
    char x[MAX]; //input1
    char y[MAX]; //input2

    int length1; // length of first word
    int length2; // length of second word

    printf("PLS, enter the first word:");
    fgets(x, sizeof(x), stdin);
    printf("PLS, enter the second word:");
    fgets(y, sizeof(y), stdin);

    length1 = length(x);
    length2 = length(y);

    equation(x, y, length1, length2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you enter celek for input1 and input2, output will be 3. This is true answer. Btw, I try to learn C and I am very new at stackoverflow. Thanks for the helps

Comment: If you enter `"celek"` twice, how is 3 the correct answer? Aren't those 4 common letters `'c', 'e', 'l', 'k'`?